# Using mailcatcher in cloud9 ide

Tags: cloud9-ide, mailcatcher

I'd like to use mailcatcher to preview emails without sending them in my Cloud9 environment. I've started up the mailcatcher daemon but can't access the server.

I'm guessing it's simply that port 1080 is not accessible in my environment. Does anyone know how I might get this set up?

Answer (score 3):

1. To start mailcatcher and access it on Cloud9

> mailcatcher --http-port $PORT --http-ip $IP and you can access it from https://project_name-username.c9.io/

2. If you want to kill the same process, list it using and kill -9 it :)

> netstat -tulpn | grep :1025

Answer (score 0):

If you run mailcatcher on port 8080 you should able to access it externally by going to http://projectname-username.c9.io

Comment: I just tried running mailcatcher with the following command, which does start the mailcatcher service on port 8080:

mailcatcher --http-port $PORT

I still can't access it using my workspace's URL. Also, if this did work I wouldn't be able to run my rails application from which the emails are sent.

Any other thoughts?